# Cloud Backup Providers for Xen Hypervisor

Tags: backup, xen

Using the XCP toolset on the server side, are any good solutions to backup up each server to the cloud (Approximately 1TB each).  What I am looking for is the ability to do a bare metal backup in case local backups fail.  Are there any Commercial solutions that provide this?  Are there any open source solutions that provide this using Amazon or other such provider as a backend?

Answer (score 0):

Not being able to get an answer on here I continued looking.  I will modify this answer as I get more information and am able to evaluate the options below:

Open Source / Free Solutions:

1) http://pipposan.wordpress.com/2011/03/15/xenserver-backup-updated-2-2/

2) http://blog.andyburton.co.uk/index.php/2009-08/citrix-xenserver-automated-live-vm-backup-to-windows-cifs-share/

2a) http://blog.andyburton.co.uk/index.php/2009-11/updated-citrix-xenserver-5-5-automatic-vm-backup-scripts/

3) http://www.8layer8.com/?p=260

4) https://github.com/markround/XenServer-snapshot-backup

Commercial Solutions:

1) http://quorumsoft.com/learnmore.php

2) http://www.phdvirtual.com/citrix-backup/overview

I'm still looking for more solutions and evaluating these.  Worse case scenario I will create a custom solution and open source it.